# Accessing Python2.x and 3.x in windows

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.5

I have successfully installed `Python2.7` and `Python3.5` on my windows machine.
The location for `Python2.7` is `C:\Python27` while the location for `Python3.5` is `C:\Python35-32`. I have added both these paths in my environment variables(path to Python27 being referred first).

Q:From the command prompt(via any directory),when i type python, it always opens the `python2.7 interactive shell`.Is there a way by which i can explicitly call Python2.7 or 3.5 on my choice? (I tried `python3` --doesn't work,am i missing something) Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked using the below:

```
py -2
```

always calls python2.x

```
py -3
```

always calls python3.x